# $this->request->data EMPTY - When I have disabled Fields CakePHP 2

Tags: forms, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I have a form which has some disabled fields, when the form is submitted both $this->request->data and $_POST is empty, removing the disabled fields and it is fine again. I would have though it would still pass though the non-disabled fields. I've even tried to remove the disabled field attribute when the submit button is pushed but this still returns an empty array.

Is there something cake related that might be causing this?

Thanks

// SNIPPET FROM THE VIEW CODE:

```
$this->Form->create('Card', array('class' => 'GeneralValidate'));

$this->Form->input('Card.property_id', array('type'=>'select', 'empty'=>true , 'class' => 'required adminOnlyField', 'div' => array('class' => 'required'))); 
$this->Form->input('Card.building_id', array('type'=>'select', 'empty'=>true, 'id' => 'BuildingSelector', 'class' => 'adminOnlyField', 'label' => 'Building (If Applicable)')); 
$this->Form->input('Prospect.waiting_list_details', array('value' => $prospect['Prospect']['waiting_list_details']));
$this->Form->input('SaleDetail.property_sold', array('class' => 'checkbox', 'checked' => $ps_checked));
$this->Form->input('SaleDetail.date_conditions_met', array('type'=>'text', 'class' => 'text date_picker adminOnlyField', 'value' => $this->Date->format($saledetail['SaleDetail']['date_conditions_met'])));
$this->Form->button('Save & Continue', array('type'=>'submit', 'label' => 'Save', 'name' => 'quicksave' , 'class' => 'submit long clear_ready_only'));
```

// JS FROM THE VIEW

```
$(function () {

var $adminOnly = $('.adminOnlyField');
$adminOnly.prop('disabled',true).prop('readonly',true);
$adminOnly.attr("onclick","return false");
$adminOnly.attr("onkeydown","return false");
$adminOnly.removeClass('required');
$adminOnly.removeClass('date_picker');



$('.clear_ready_only').click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $adminOnly.prop('disabled',false).prop('readonly',false);
    $adminOnly.attr("onclick","return true");
    $adminOnly.attr("onkeydown","return true");
    $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the disabled option from this, leaving the ready only and added some addition CSS stylings so it looked disabled to the user. This is not the exact answer to the question but works as a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way HTML works, disabled don't get posted. CakePHP can't change what is sent from the browser. If you still want the value you can set it as a hidden element.

### Update

Some problems I see:

1. Missing `Form::end()` in view (always a [good idea](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#closing-the-form) to insert it).
2. You never said your form was submitted from JS, first test with a simple form POST then JS.
3. Your JS code is set to submit a form by ID `CardModifysaleForm`. There's no such ID in your supplied view code and you're not setting your form to that ID from the snippet you supply.

Comment: I understand that but I thought the non-disabled fields should still come though? I have 3 disabled fields on the form and 10 non disabled fields, when the 3 are disabled the other data doesn't come though as well?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear at first that when you post you don't get any fields from your question. Can you please update your question with your view code?

Comment: OK thanks, I hacve put in a snippet of the code, the form create line, a few lines with the disabled class and some without and then the button. I also put in the jquery I am running to get this to disable / enable.